# Where to put reverse= True?

Tags: python

This code is meant to sort integers in a csv file from high to low.

```
class1=open('Class1.csv','r')
csv1=csv.reader(class1, delimiter=',')
sort=sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for eachline in sort:
    print (eachline)
```

I've seen similar examples using `reverse=True`, as it is meant to sort the data in a descending order (high to low), but I can't figure out how to use it in this type of code. If you could explain where it should and why, it would be very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put it here:

```
sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: sort=sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reversed=True)                     I tried it and it came up with this error:
TypeError: 'reversed' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @SOPHIE101 You have `reversed`. It should be `reverse` without a `d`.